# Can I combine these 2 commands? (or am I fighting a losing battle?)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm very new to ffmpeg but so far I'm enjoying it. But I'm stuck on something. I want to combine these two commands into one, something I'm sure must be possible, but after countless hours and no luck, here I am :)

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "tmp.images.txt" -i "tmp.audio.mp3" -filter_complex "drawbox=y=ih-38:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=38:t=fill, drawtext=fontfile=Assets/calibrib.ttf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=white:fontsize=14:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h)-24" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "tmp.slide.mp4"

ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "Assets/studio.jpg" -i tmp.slide.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=879:496[inner];[0][inner]overlay=207:49:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a aac -y tmp.output.mp4
```

the first line creates a slideshow and places text at bottom

the second line takes the slideshow video and inserts it into a background image before outputting final video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "tmp.images.txt" -i "tmp.audio.mp3" -i "Assets/studio.jpg" -filter_complex "[0]drawbox=y=ih-38:color=black@0.6:width=iw:height=38:t=fill, drawtext=fontfile=Assets/calibrib.ttf:text='%%~ni':fontcolor=white:fontsize=14:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h)-24,scale=879:496[inner];[2][inner]overlay=207:49" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune stillimage -c:a aac -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p "tmp.slide.mp4"`

Comment: Hi Gyan, thank you again, it works perfect. I'm a PHP developer myself and new to CMD/FFmpeg so its all a little confusing. I don't think I'll ever get my head around those square bracket things, i.e. [0:a] and [inner] etc. I don't understand the logic in them and how they work.